# Attached an anonymous type to an object; how to retrieve it? 

Tags: c#, reflection, anonymous-types

I'm playing with the .NET `BackgroundWorker` class.  As part of its functionality you can call a method named `ReportProgress` that allows you to pass in the percentage your background task has completed, along with an optional user parameter.

Eventually `ReportProgress` calls an event handler and the optional user parameter becomes the "UserState" member of the event argument.

Here's a quick sample in case I'm not being clear:

```
BackgroundProcess.ReportProgress(100, new{title="complete"});
/*****later on, this method is called******/
private void myEventHandler(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   //e.UserState is my anonymous type defined in the call to ReportProgress(...)
}
```

My question is, how can I access the "title" value in my anonymous type?  I assume I'll need to use reflection but so far I'm not having great luck.

Comment: I know it's annoying to have to define silly one-off types, but by far the most idiomatic and cleanest solution will be to just define a named type here with a title property.  Why bother with reflection?

Comment: But if all you need is the title, why define an object at all? Just pass a string and cast it to string in the event handler.

Comment: Your questions are completely valid, but at this point it's an academic question for me-- I've been fiddling with getting this to work with reflection and everytime I think I have it, I don't.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are using C# 4.0:

```
dynamic o = e.UserState;
o.title;
```

You *can* use reflection, but it would be big, slow and ugly.  A named type would be more sensible.

Answer (score 3):

Don't use anonymous objects. They are scoped only to the current method. Once you leave the scope of the current method in which they are defined accessing them becomes a PITA. So define a simple class and then cast to this class:

```
BackgroundProcess.ReportProgress(100, new MyClass { Title = "complete" });
```

and then:

```
private void myEventHandler(object sender, RunWorkerCompletedEventArgs e)
{
   var title = ((MyClass)e.UserState).Title;
}
```

Comment: Thanks-- I see what you mean by the PITA part of trying it my way.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot and there is no reason why you should not create a class to pass the values.

**On possibility** is casting to `dynamic` and then getting the property but **I do not recommend it**.